# Is possible get a table from another server(Mysql) in my table(Sql)?

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp-3.x

I have 2 connections in my project and I need get a table from database dbservermysql in my table in dbserversql. Are 2 databases from 2 differents server. This is possible with Cakephp 3.8?

I tried:

```
$result = $this->VacancyControl->find('search', ['search' => $filter])
         ->select(['user' => 'b.NAME'])
         ->join([
         'b' => [
         'table' => 'BUser',
         'type' => 'LEFT',
         'conditions' => 'b.ID = VacancyControl.user_id',
      ]);
```

VacancyControl come from the database dbserversql and BUser come from dbservermysql.
When I call in postman get->http://localhost/api/BUser I got my response normally. 
But when I call get->http://localhost/api/VacancyControl i got this error: Error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'BUser&#039

My connections:

```
...
'dbservermysql ' => [
            'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
            'driver' =>  'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
            'host' => '...',
            'username' => '...',
            'password' => '....',
            'database' => 'dbservermysql ',
            'persistent' => false,
            'encoding' => 'utf8',
        ],
 'dbserversql ' => [
            'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
            'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Sqlserver',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => '...',
            'username' => '....',
            'password' => '....',
            'database' => 'dbserversql ',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'flags' => [],
            'cacheMetadata' => true,
            'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
            'log' => false,
            'url' => env('DATABASE_TEST_URL', null)
        ],
...
```

Is possible get BUser in VacancyControl? If yes, how can I do this?

Comment: The link is about how to do joins between different databases in general. You're going to need to solve that problem first before you'll have any chance of doing it in Cake.

Comment: Yeah, this works to me.. Thank you very much